# No HDMI sound on INTEL NUC NUC5I3RYH

Tags: 16.04, sound, hdmi, intel-nuc

I upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I lost audio on HDMI. Headphones work fine.

Some information about my system:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

_

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.0-83-generic (buildd@lgw01-29) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017
```

-

```
$ pacmd list-cards
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xaa034000 irq 48"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "160c"
        device.product.name = "Broadwell-U Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xaa030000 irq 47"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9ca0"
        device.product.name = "Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
```

-

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xaa034000 irq 48
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xaa030000 irq 47
```

Should I upgrade to another version of ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

Next time you connect the HDMI open the sound settings. HDMI output should be listed along with your internal audio output. Select the HDMI output. 
After that open terminal and type

```
pulseaudio -k
```

This worked fine for me I hope it works for yours.

Comment: HDMI output is listed and that's what's selected.
`pulseaudio -k ` didn't fix the problem

Comment: In selecting the HDMI as output try changing the mode in the HDMI settings to the first option. If that doesn't work you can also try installing pulseaudio volume control by
`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol `. Open pulseaudio volume control and under the configuration tab switch to HDMI from the built-in audio profile.

Comment: Perhaps see if this answer helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/944735/silent-hdmi-sound-with-nuc6cayh-16-04