# Silent HDMI sound with NUC6CAYH 16.04

Tags: sound, hdmi, intel-nuc

I have an Intel NUC6CAYH connected to a not very new Samsung 42" TV. When I go to sound settings and select "Play sound through" "HDMI / Displayport", the software seems to think everything is OK, but no sound is produced.

I checked that everything is umuted in alsamixer, and pavucontrol shows that sound is being produced.

Comment: For the record, this is not an Ubuntu-only issue. I have the same problem on Mageia 6 with an HDMI 1.3 LG TV. The xset/... trick from the answer below does help, but the sound breaks down frequently enough to make even this workaround painful.

Answer (score 3):

After much experimentation, I found that putting the display to sleep (e.g. when the screen is turned off after a period of inactivity), waking it, and then restarting pulseaudio makes the sound work until the next reboot.

I'm using the PC as an HTPC that loads kodi at bootup, so I automated this by creating a little script to launch kodi:

```
#! /bin/sh

xset dpms force off
sleep 1
pulseaudio -k
sleep 1
/usr/bin/kodi -fs
```

In earlier attempts at fixing the issue I set pulseaudio to never let the sound device sleep (commented out `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`), and also set the default sampling rate to 48000 (`default-sample-rate = 48000` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`). Not sure if these settings contributed to the fix, but they are not sufficient on their own.

I also reported a bug against Ubuntu 16.04:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1709708